# Update dictionary in xml from csv file in python

Tags: python, xml, csv, key

Okay, so I have the following .csv file which contains:

```
AAC=1|1|1,AAK=1|2|8
```

I want to write that file to the following .xml file:

```
<html>
  <A>
    <B>
      <C>
        <D>
          <TYPE>
            <NUMBER>7297</NUMBER>
            <DATA />
          </TYPE>
          <TYPE>
            <NUMBER>7721</NUMBER>
            <DATA>AAC=7|3|8,ABC=1|3|5,DAK=5|1|3,FFK=33</DATA>
          </TYPE>
        </D>
      </C>
    </B>
  </A>
</html>
```

I want to specifically write it to the  part under the 7721 so the updated .xml file would looks like:

```
<html>
  <A>
    <B>
      <C>
        <D>
          <TYPE>
            <NUMBER>7297</NUMBER>
            <DATA />
          </TYPE>
          <TYPE>
            <NUMBER>7721</NUMBER>
            <DATA>AAC=1|1|1,AAK=1|2|8,ABC=1|3|5,DAK=5|1|3,FFK=33</DATA>
          </TYPE>
        </D>
      </C>
    </B>
  </A>
</html>
```

As you can see if the key is already exist on both the .csv and the .xml then it will only update the value on the .xml file, but if both the key and value on the .csv file does not exist on the .xml file then it will add both those key and value to the .xml file.

My code so far:

```
element = etree.fromstring(xmlData)

# Find all the TYPE with NUMBER=7721 and DATA
optype_nodes = element.xpath("//TYPE[NUMBER='7721' and DATA]")

for t in optype_nodes:
    d = t.find('DATA')
    d.text = 'csvdata'
print etree.tostring(element)
```

Just ended up importing all the .csv content and replace the .xml content completely.

Thank you!

Comment: If this is working fine, your question would be?

Comment: I want to update the <DATA> part based from the .csv file. Right now it is just completely overwrite whatever is on the .xml with whatever it is on the .csv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let's write a function that turns one of your strings (from csv or xml) into a dictionary:

```
def string_to_dict(string):
    # Split the string on commas
    list_of_entries = string.split(',')
    # Each of these entries needs to be split on '='
    # We'll use a list comprehension
    list_of_split_entries = map(lambda e: e.split('='), list_of_entries)
    # Now we have a list of (key, value) pairs.  We can pass this
    # to the dict() function to get a dictionary out of this, and 
    # that's what we want to return
    return dict(list_of_split_entries)
```

Now we want to get this dictionary for both the csv data and the xml data:

```
csv_dict = string_to_dict(csv_data)
# csv_dict = {'AAK': '1|2|8', 'AAC': '1|1|1'}
xml_dict = string_to_dict(d.text)
# xml_dict = {'ABC': '1|3|5', 'FFK': '33', 'AAC': '7|3|8', 'DAK': '5|1|3'}
```

Using the [update](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict) function, we can add the values from csv_dict to xml_dict, overwriting where they're the same:

```
xml_dict.update(csv_dict)
# xml_dict = {'ABC': '1|3|5', 'FFK': '33', 'AAC': '1|1|1', 'AAK': '1|2|8', 'DAK': '5|1|3'}
```

Now we need to get `xml_dict` back into a string.  The simple way to do this is:

```
# Let's get a list of key=value strings
list_of_items = ['%s=%s' % (k, v) for k, v in xml_dict.iteritems()]
# Now join those items together
new_xml_text = ','.join(list_of_items)
d.text = new_xml_text
```

If you want to keep them sorted, you can do it this way:

```
d.text = ','.join('%s=%s' % (k, xml_dict[k]) for k in sorted(xml_dict.keys()))
```

Answer (score 0):

I m not sure if this is possible for you, meaning: if you are bound to xml file structure you included in the question or not. 
If you can freely choose the structure, you could take advantage of XML and store the data like this:

```
<TYPE>
   <NUMBER>7297</NUMBER>
   <DATA />
</TYPE>
<TYPE>
  <NUMBER>7721</NUMBER>
  <DATA>
    <AAC>1|1|1</AAC>
    <AAK>1|2|8</AAK>
    <ABC>1|3|5</ABC>
    <DAK>5|1|3</DAK>
  <DATA>
</TYPE>
```

This way you could update specific values more easily and access them via xpath.
For preparing the retrieved csvStr for the xml structure you could use split():

```
lst = csvStr.split(',')
for dataStr in lst:
    data = dataStr.split('=')
    #data[0]: var name, data[1]: var value
```

Hope this helps a little bit.

Comment: Yes, I am bound to the xml structure so this won't be possible. I am thinking about using dictionary but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

So, wanted to update `d.text`. One of the way to do that would be convert to dictionary and update and then write back to d.text. When you write it back make sure you are having the order proper as you want for the csv. I see it is alphabet. Ensure that is the case. Because we are converting to dictionary and then updating, we run the risk of changing the order.

```
def get_csv_dict(csv_line):

    return dict([(k,v) for k, v in map(lambda x: x.split('='), csv_line)])

contents = get_csv_dict(d.text)
required_contents = get_csv_dict(csvdata)
contents.update(required_contents)
```

Then do

```
>>> temp = []
>>> for key in sorted(contents.keys()):
...     temp.append(key + '=' + contents[key])
... 
>>> d.text = ",".join(temp)
```

You will find `d.text` updated as you desired.